# Simple JSON Server

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

How to parse this type of json in android:

```
{
"chatCircles": [{
    "id": "59660c155d44f20b46eab438",
    "name": "Hyderabad Circle",
    "description": "Hyderabad"
}]
}
```

I have tried this but UI is not updating.

```
try {
        JSONArray chatCircleArray = response.getJSONArray("chatCircle");
        for (int i = 0; i < chatCircleArray.length(); i++){
           JSONObject geoFenceObject = chatCircleArray.getJSONObject(i);
           circleId = geoFenceObject.getString("id");
           String circleName = geoFenceObject.getString("name");
           String location = geoFenceObject.getString("description");
           Log.d(TAG, "GeoFenceObject Chat Circle Id parsed is:\t " + circleId);
           System.out.println("Chat Circle id is: \t" + circleId);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Pls help. How to do this json parsing?

Comment: `getJSONArray("chatCircle");`...? Did you mean `getJSONArray("chatCircles");`?

Comment: Yes, thank you soo much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first brace is a JSONObject that you didn't parse. 
Try the code below.

```
try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

        JSONArray itemArray = json.getJSONArray("chatCircles");
        for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject subJson = (JSONObject) itemArray.get(i);
            String id = subJson.getString("id");
            String name = subJson.getString("name");
            String description = subJson.getString("description");
            Log.i("TEST", "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", description=" + description);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That did it. Need to be more careful now. Thanks all